# Is there any way to send an alert message (callback.answer(text, show_alert=True) without getting a callback data from an inline button?

Tags: python, callback, message, aiogram, message-handlers

I know that the alert-message can only be received if the user clicks on the inline button and sends the callback data to the bot. But I want an alarm message to be sent if, say, I wrote the wrong message in bot's chat. In this case, my messages are processed by the message handler and the callback data is not sent anywhere. Is it possible to send an alert-message just like that, without first sending a callback data

I tried to write directly:

```
@dp.message_handler
async def Answer (message: Message)
     await message.answer('text', show_alert=True)
```

but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

no, since the script sends these messages by the message 'id', and it is only available when the button (callback) is pressed. in any other case you only have a 'message_id', you can't send it